# delete 1 object AngularJS from rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I tried to delete 1 object from massif.
Massif storage on rails server. 
You can see it

```
localhost/vms
{"success":true,"vms":[{"name":"test"},
{"name":"dfdfdfd"}]}
```

And i need to delete "test"(first object from massif).
How can i do this?

When i used, I got a rails error, that ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/vms"):

```
$http.delete('localhost/vms', name)
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :vms, only: [:index, :create, :delete], defaults: { format: 'json' }
end
```

Comment: You are using the plural routes,  but calling routes as singular routes. you need to pass the id of object you want to delete. like `localhost/vms/:id`. For more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: i can't do this, because i need to change vm's model, but i can't do this, may be are some another variants?

Comment: okay, use `$http.delete('localhost/vms/'+name) ` and in rails controller `vm = VMS.find_by_name(params[:id])`

Comment: When i did the thing, that you have said i got a wrong message: to autoload constant VM, expected /home/app/models/vm.rb to define it

Comment: You need to put your model name there. I just used `VMS` as example because i don't the name of model you have used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the plural routes, so you need specify the id while calling the routes. for eg.

```
$http.delete('localhost/vms/'+name)
```

and in your rails controller

```
def destroy
  # param[:id] contains the name as we are passing name instead of id .
  vm = Vm.find_by_name(params[:id])
  vm.destroy
end
```